# DB2 Stored Procedure COBOL with temporary table

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

We are just beginning to use COBOL stored procedures, but we are having a problem when using temporary tables. After we make the call to the COBOL program the connection times out. CMTSTAT is set to inactive. I'm thinking the problem is with the declare of the temp table with the on commit preserver rows, but don't know how to get around this. Any thoughts would be helpful

Comment: Please include source with your question. The better your problem is described, the more likely you will be to get help.

Answer (score 0):

Actually found the answer to my question. We ended up doing a drop of the temporary table from the calling program and that worked.